# How to check for valid object in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have inherited code that parses from a web service and fills in a `NSDictionary`. Under some circumstances, which I am going to explore, the parser returns a `NSDictionary` with count of 5, but the objects are invalid. Any message sent to them fails with unrecognized selector, even `isKindOfClass:` fails.

When I **po** the object in console, I see this:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid
ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

How can I check that the object is invalid, if `isKindOfClass:` does not work here?

Here is the output from the console during the crash. You see dictionary with 5 empty objects, po on object 9 returns the invalid message.

[image]

Here is the po of the big dictionary:

[image]

I hope I will be able to check the issue in the parser, but I am also interested in how can I check for that invalid object to prevent the crash.

Comment: What happens when you `po` the dictionary itself?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Can you show sample JSON?

Comment: When I po the dictionary itself, I see a valid dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access an element of dictionary using an integer, if the object is a dictionary, the key should be any obj-c object that comforms to copy protocol. You are using 0 as an `integer` index, primitive types aren't obj-c objects, you should wrap it into an `NSNumber`.
The other issue is that the `NSJSONSerializer` returns an `id` type object, basing on the structure of the parsed JSON this could be a dictionary or an array, you should always inspect the returned object to check the type. I usually always expect an arrays of dictionaries, if the system returns just a dictionary, I create an array on the fly with just that object.

Comment: (lldb) po [self.surveys[0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: (lldb) po [self.surveys[0] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: The debugger says surveys is a mutable dictionary, you are accessing it as an array

Comment: the answer is wrong.. it is not: probably returning an NSArray ;)

Comment: Later I will update the answer with the comments facts

Comment: This is interesting. self.surveys is declared as `NSArray` and it works perfectly in cellForRow, where I access its objects by index. In the bad scenario, when the parser returns some bad data, it is seen in the console as NSDictionary, causing accessing the index to crash. I will protect against that, but I am wondering how a class declared as NSArray can become NSDictionary.

Comment: Depends on the method (selector) you are sending to that object. For instance both arrays and dictionaries have a count method. We you send something that is not implemented or declared you got a crash such as unrecognized selector. This is why obcjC is dynamic language, this is due to the nature of that language. The parser returns an id object and if you don't cast compiler don't know which kind of object you are sending messages.

Comment: I agree and I can see that now in the parser: `result = dictionary[@"Surveys"][@"Survey"];` This can return anything what is on that path. I have added checks for the kind of object here and it now works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

your po wants an array - but it is a dictionary.

this wont work

a dictionary can not be indexed with integers as it doesnt have `objectForSubscriptIndex`

Comment: I can see it now. Don't know what I was thinking about. Thank you.